# Switch Toggle is not switching in react until i refresh it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, toggle

I am calling API and populating the data off it and here is the toggle switch. when I will check or uncheck the toggle switch in which I am sending **id** and **status** to the server. Hence my Api is working fine but the problem is that my toggle switch is not properly switching. When I click on the toggle, it will switch when I refresh the page otherwise not. Below is my code for it. Thank you for being so helpful

```
const ManageUsersAvailability_getAvailableUsersData = async () => {
    setisLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users`,
        {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          params: {
            filterBy: null,
            filterValue: null,
            isAscending: false,
            page: numofPages - 1,
            size: pageSize,
          },
        }
      );
      let result = await response.data;
      setMUAgetAvailabeUsers(result?.Users);
      settotalUsers(result?.total);
        setisLoading(false);
      console.log(
        "get all available users data  success ==> ManageUsersAvailability_getAvailableUsersData",
        result
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "get all available users data  error ==> ManageUsersAvailability_getAvailableUsersData",
        error
      );
      throw error;
    }
  };
    const handleToggle = (e, id) => {
    // setStatus(e.target.checked)
    statusRef.current = e.target.checked
    setGetUserId(id)
 }
 const ManageUsersAvailability_toggleSwitch = async() => {
    console.log("getUserId", getUserId)
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users/insert-data/${getUserId}/${statusRef.current}`,{
            headers : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            }
          })    
          const result = await response.data
          console.log("status posted --successfully ==> ManageUsersAvailability_toggleSwitch", result)     
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error("status failed  --error ==> ManageUsersAvailability_toggleSwitch", error)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (getUserId !== undefined) {
      ManageUsersAvailability_toggleSwitch()
    }
  }, [getUserId])

 <KTCardBody className="py-4">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table
            id="kt_table_users"
            className="table align-middle table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5 dataTable no-footer"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr className="text-start text-muted fw-bold fs-7 text-uppercase gs-0">
                <th className="w-125px text-capitalize cursor-pointer">
                  {empCodeLabel?.value}
                </th>

                <th className="w-300px text-capitalize text-nowrap cursor-pointer">
                  {employeeLabel?.value}
                </th>
                <th className="text-end w-100px text-capitalize">{actionLabel?.value}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-gray-600 fw-semibold">
              {MUAgetAvailabeUsers?.length === 0 ? (
                  <>
                  <tr>
                    <td colSpan={4}>
                      {isLoading ? (
                        <>
                          <tr>
                            <td colSpan={7}>
                              <div
                                style={{
                                  ...styles,
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  textAlign: 'center',
                                }}
                              >
                                {processingLabel?.value}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          <div className='d-flex text-center  w-100 align-content-center justify-content-center'
                            style={{
                              position: 'absolute',
                              textAlign: 'center',
                            }}
                          >
                            {noMatchMsg?.value}
                          </div>
                        </>
                      )}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              ) : (
                MUAgetAvailabeUsers?.map((availableUser, index) => (
                    <tr key={"availableUser" + index}>
                      <td>{availableUser?.userId}</td>
                      <td>{availableUser?.employeeName}</td>
                      <td class="text-end">
                        <label class="d-flex flex-end form-check form-switch form-check-custom form-check-solid">
                          <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="1"
                            checked={availableUser?.status}
                            onChange={(e) => handleToggle(e, availableUser?.userId)}
                          />
                        </label>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                ))
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className='d-flex justify-content-end flex-stack flex-wrap pt-10'>
              <ul className='pagination'>
                <li
                  className={`paginate_button page-item previous ${numofPages === 1 && 'disabled'}`}
                >
                  <button
                    className='page-link cursor-pointer'
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.preventDefault()
                      paginate(numofPages - 1)
                    }}
                  >
                    <i className='previous'></i>
                  </button>
                </li>
                {MUAgetAvailabeUsers.length > 0 &&
                  pageNumbers
                    ?.slice(
                      numofPages <= 6 ? 0 : numofPages - 6,
                      numofPages + 3 > pageNumbers.length ? pageNumbers.length : numofPages + 3
                    )
                    .map((number) => (
                      <li
                        key={number}
                        className={`page-item ${numofPages === number ? 'active' : ''}`}
                      >
                        <button
                          className='page-link'
                          onClick={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault()
                            paginate(number)
                          }}
                        >
                          {number}
                        </button>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                {MUAgetAvailabeUsers.length > 0 &&
                  pageNumbers.length > 6 &&
                  numofPages <= pageNumbers.length - 4 && (
                    <li className='page-item disabled'>
                      <span className='page-link'>...</span>
                    </li>
                  )}
                <li className={`page-item next ${numofPages === pageNumbers.length && 'disabled'}`}>
                  <button
                    className='page-link cursor-pointer'
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.preventDefault()
                      paginate(numofPages + 1)
                    }}
                  >
                    <i className='next'></i>
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </KTCardBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the handleToggle function you're not doing any action, you're just console loging the  the messages with the result, you need to change your state there to be able to see changes

And also, when using axios you don't have to specify the content-type

```
 headers : {"Content-Type" : "application/json" }
```

Comment: this is handletoggle function
  const handleToggle = (e, id) => {
    // setStatus(e.target.checked)
    statusRef.current = e.target.checked
    setGetUserId(id)
 }

Comment: it's commented which means you're not doing the necassary updates to your state